# Making text bold with django

Tags: python, django

I have to send make some text bold in between plain text and send it to the template from the view. I do this:

I save a string like this <b>TextPlaintext</b> in a variable and return it to the template.
The "<b>" tags are not interpreted.

How can make some text bold in a django view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a text bold shouldn't be done in the view. Indeed, the view should not take care of formatting (which is the role of templates). What you can do however, is adding an extra variable to the rendering context, and depending on its value, make the text bold or not in the template.

For example :

In the view :

```
#...
is_important = True if something else False
extra_context.update({'is_important': is_important})
#...
```

In the template :

```
...
{% if is_important %}<b>{{ text_to_render }}</b>{% else %}{{ text_to_render }}{% endif %}
...
```

But **more generally**, deciding if a text is bold or not, is not even formatting, rather styling and should not be made in the template (so you shouldn't use the <*bold>* markup). So I would suggest :

```
...
<span {% if is_important %}class="is-important"{% endif %}>
{{ text_to_render }}
</span>
...
```

And a stylesheet :

```
.is-important{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Django automatically escapes string values in templates, to improve security.

If you know that a value has HTML in it, *and is trusted*, then you can turn off escaping:

```
{{my_trusted_html|safe}}
```

Comment: +1 for being *correct*, but the OP is making a more fundamental mistake in doing any kind of text formatting in the view, as @Sébastien Piquemal points out.

Comment: I'm not so dogmatic as you, I guess.  There are reasons for creating HTML content in a view, or even in a model, or stored in a database.  Knowing how to get that data onto the page correctly is a useful tool.  I don't presume to know enough about the OP's problem to say whether he is doing something as bad as "making a mistake".

Comment: Agreed.  I am building an application where "rules" are dynamically displayed which were populated in the database.  Certain words in these rules are bolded, or underlined.  Not the whole line, btw, which makes the accepted answer unusable.  The template is for rendering the look of the data, and here I'd argue the data itself already contains info about how it should be rendered.  Pushing that application logic to the view is unnecessary and inefficient (and can't be done when only a portion of the text should display formatted text).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [autoescape](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape) tag in a django template.

Also, if you write your own filter, you can [control whether or not it is escaped](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping).